# Update another objects style in a stylesheet

Tags: css

I'm wondering if it's possible to update another objects style from a stylesheet, like this example wants to show h1 when you hover over a:

```
a:hover { set h1:display:block; }

h1 { display: none; }
```

Is this possible in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the `h1` in the `a`, then you could use this style:

```
h1 {display:none;}
a:hover h1 {display:block;}
```

If the `h1` comes right after the `a`, then you can use this:

```
h1 {display:none}
a:hover + h1 {display:block;}
```

Otherwise, you'd have to use Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You can style an element depending on some "state" of a preceding element ("state" being an attribute or its value, an element, class or id) with **`+`** and **`~`**.
This element needs to be a **parent or preceding sibling of a parent** (but not a descendant of the latter).

```
    h1 > span ~ a { /* will style a, not h1 */ }

    a:hover + h1 { /* will style h1 if next sibling of an element a being hovered.
                      I prefer to wrap inline elements such as a in a block element such as p for example, so it wouldn't work there,
                      but HTML5 is more permissive with links surrounding block elements and such */ }
```

Maybe what you want to ultimately achieve could be done by hacking the CSS3 **:target** as in the demos of http://ie7nomore.com/#CSS3 labelled :target (that won't be on :hover anymore obviously)

Don't foget to have the [same behavior for :focus as for :hover, for non-mouse users](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/C15.html) (keyboard and other devices). And add :active because some IEs are buggy.

Comment: +1 for the General Sibling selector - I'd forgotten about that. IMO this should be the accepted answer because of the `~` selector, but that's the OP's choice not mine :-) By the way, why do you like wrapping inline elements in block elements? That surely defeats the purpose of an inline element.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not, unless your `h1` is a child of `a`. You can get away with siblings using the `+` siblings selector (demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/ZkGxp/), but other than that this isn't possible. For example,

```
/* Show <h1> element inside <a> on hover */
a:hover h1 {
    display: block;
}

/* Show <h1> adjacent to <a> when hovered */
a:hover + h1 {
    display: block;
}
```

Your only other option here is JavaScript. If you're using a framework like jQuery or Mootools already, this is fantastically easy, but it's pretty simple with vanilla JavaScript too.